# How to use a switch case statement in a while loop

Tags: php

I have a function where you can press the button shuffle, and then you get three random rows from MySQL database, with the columnnames `id, weekday, description`. At the moment I just get random rows without any conditions. Therefore I made a select form, where I can choose to only get printed records, when weekday is equal to wednesday.

I tried to make a switch case statement, but I am really not sure how I have to set that in my while loop?

[image: Shuffle]

**index.php**

```
<select name="weekday" class="form-control selectpicker" >
        <option value=" ">Select Weekday</option>
        <option value="alldays">All Days</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Shuffle</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Shuffle Result</h4><hr>
    <?php include 'shuffle.php' ?>
</div>
```

**shuffle.php**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, description FROM articles ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 3";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    //print($res);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Number: " . $row["id"]. "<br>" .
                 "Description: " . $row["description"]. "<br><br>".
                 '<div class="btn btn-warning btn-open-modal" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">See Details '.'</div><br><br>';              
        }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
```

I tried to make a switch case code for my while loop:

```
switch($_POST['weekday']){
          case 'alldays':
              echo "Alldays";
          break;
          case 'wednesday':
              echo "Wednesday";
          break;
          case 'saturday':
              echo "Saturday";
          break;
          default:
              echo "Something went wrong";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your desired outcome properly, the switch would not go in the while loop. You would use it to alter the query. Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, description FROM articles";
switch($_POST['weekday']){
      case 'alldays':
          //you can remove this case because it does change the query
      break;
      case 'wednesday':
          $sql .= " WHERE day LIKE 'wednesday'";
      break;
      case 'saturday':
          $sql .= " WHERE day LIKE 'saturday'";
      break;
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 3";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Please realize that I do not know your database structure so the column names I used in the WHERE statements may have to be changed.

In response to your comment: The reason why you are getting that undefined index is because your select element is outside of your form. Change it to this:

```
<form method='post'>
    <select name="weekday" class="form-control selectpicker" >
        <option value=" ">Select Weekday</option>
        <option value="alldays">All Days</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Shuffle</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <h4>Shuffle Result</h4><hr>
    <?php include 'shuffle.php' ?>
</div>
```

For future reference, a quick way to test a page like this is to add:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This will show you what post values actually made it to the page. If you would have done that you would have seen that your POST variable did not have the information you were looking for

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. The only place I am actually getting an error with your code is in: `switch($_POST['weekday'])` where it says: `Undefined index`

Comment: That is because your SELECT element is outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

hello but I think its not possible to have the post echo in index.php

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. So I have to set my php code on my index.php?

Comment: Yesterday I made the same mistake. I was advise to use XHR (AJAX) or websockets to send the data back to the server without reloading the whole page or navigating to another page.